# How to make nginx serve on HTTP

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx instance that serves everything fine on HTTPS but not on HTTP.

When I go to `http://myserver.com/something` then it just hands, however, if I go to `https://myserver.com/something` then it serves the page.

This is how my paths look for `sites-available`

```
root@myserver:~# ls -al /etc/nginx/sites-available/
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May 11 15:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Feb 11 22:46 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  586 Oct  6  2015 default
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1901 Oct  6  2015 default.orig
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 11 15:30 locations
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1460 May 11 15:37 ssl_proxy
```

This is my path for `sites-enabled`

```
root@myserver:~# ls -al /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 11 15:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Feb 11 22:46 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Jun 29  2016 ssl_proxy -> ../sites-available/ssl_proxy
```

My `ssl_proxy` looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/key.pem;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ca.pem;

    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;


    # modern configuration. tweak to your needs.
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (15768000 seconds = 6 months)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    # OCSP Stapling ---
    # fetch OCSP records from URL in ssl_certificate and cache them
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;


    resolver <ipaddress_here>;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/locations/*.conf;
}
```

**Question**

How can I have `http` be served as well?

Comment: You've shown your HTTPS configuration. What does your HTTP configuration look like?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't serve content on both protocols, you should forward from http to https

```
# Forward non-www requests to www
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  example.com www.example.com;
  return       301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

If you really want to server http in that server above you need to tell Nginx to listen on port 80. The config would start like this

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
  listen       80;  # NEW LINE
  # etc
}
```

This is trivial Nginx. Before you ask similar questions I suggest you do some research and learning of your own.